# Error when trying to send email attachment

Tags: python, email, flask, flask-mail

I'm using the following function in my program to send emails:

```
def send_email(subject, sender, recipients, text_body):
    FILE_TYPES = set(['txt', 'doc', 'docx', 'odt', 'pdf', 'rtf', 'text', 'wks', 'wps', 'wpd'])
    form = ApplicationForm (request.files)
    submit_name = form.file_upload.data.filename
    mail = Mail(app)
    msg = Message(subject, sender=sender, recipients=recipients)
    msg.body = text_body
    if '.' in submit_name and submit_name.rsplit('.', 1)[1] in FILE_TYPES:
        filename = secure_filename(submit_name)
        form.file_upload.data.save('uploads/' + filename)
        with app.open_resource(filename) as fp:
            msg.attach(filename, fp.read())
            mail.send(msg)
```

The email works fine and sends to the to the correct user, however the attatchment does not, I believe I may be referencing this incorrectly as the file attachment comes from the form.

I have used the function below to save the attachment and this works fine so I'm not sure why the above is not working, can anyone assist?

```
if '.' in submit_name and submit_name.rsplit('.', 1)[1] in FILE_TYPES:
    filename = secure_filename(submit_name)
    form.file_upload.data.save('uploads/' + filename)
    return redirect('home')
```

Edit: When trying to submit error message received is:

```
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\richard.danvers\\application\\answer.docx'
```

Looks as if 'uploads' is not included in the path, anyone know how to include this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A content type needs to be specified within the msg.attach argument.

e.g. 'text/plain'

Answer (score 0):

You are sending the email before attaching the files:

```
mail.send(msg)
if '.' in submit_name and submit_name.rsplit('.', 1)[1] in FILE_TYPES:
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks, have edited post. Still receiving following error message: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\richard.danvers\\application\\answer.docx'